# Double integral over special region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I need to calculate the value of the integral
[image]

Over the region between the four lines [image]

I thought I could perhaps define the region using

```
Boole[{-8 <= 2 x + 3 y <= 8 && -2 <= 5 x + 2 y <= 2}]
```

but that doesn't work. ("Incomplete; more input is needed").

What functions can be used to solve this problem?

Comment: The region should be defined as  `reg = ImplicitRegion[ -2 <= 2 x + 7 y <= 2 && -2 <= 3 x + 6 y <= 2 , {x, y}]` I think.

Comment: You are nearly there with "Boole": `NIntegrate[
 Boole[-8 <= 2 x + 3 y <= 8 && -2 <= 5 x + 2 y <= 2], {x, -10, 
  10}, {y, -10, 10}]` this yields:  5.81818

Comment: See also [Double integral over a parallelogram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41163/double-integral-over-a-parallelogram)

Answer (score 8):

- Method 1

```
Integrate[
 Boole[{ -2 <= 2 x + 7 y <= 2 && -2 <= 3 x + 6 y <= 2}](6 x^2 + 
    33 x*y + 42 y^2)^4, {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]
```

> `4096/225`

- Method 2

```
Integrate[(6 x^2 + 33 x*y + 42 y^2)^4, {x, y} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[{ -2 <= 2 x + 7 y <= 2 && -2 <= 3 x + 6 y <= 2}, {x, 
    y}]]
```

> `4096/225`

- Method 3

```
(* change of variables *)
sol = Solve[{u == 2 x + 7 y, v == 3 x + 6 y}, {x, y}][[1]];
(*  {x -> 1/9 (-6 u + 7 v), y -> 1/9 (3 u - 2 v)}  *)
expr = (6 x^2 + 33 x*y + 42 y^2)^4 /. sol // Simplify;
(* u^4 v^4 *)
jacobian = Grad[{x, y} /. sol, {u, v}] // Det // Abs
(* 1/9 *)
Integrate[expr*jacobian, {u, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2}]
```

> `4096/225`

- Method 4

```
Factor[6 x^2 + 33 x*y + 42 y^2]
(* 3 (x + 2 y) (2 x + 7 y) *)
```

It means that the integrand `(6 x^2 + 33 x*y + 42 y^2)^4` is just `(u*v)^4` if we set `u=3(x+2y)` and `v=2x+7y`.

Then the region became `-2<=u<=2` and `-2<=v<=2`.

To calculate `Grad[{x,y},{u,v}]//Det`, we just need to calculate `1/Grad[{u,v},{x,y}]//Det`.

```
1/(Grad[{3(x+2y),2x+7y}, {x, y}] // Det // Abs)
```

`1/9`

```
Clear[u,v];
Integrate[(u*v)^4*1/9,{u,-2,2},{v,-2,2}]
```

> `4096/225`

Comment: Are you sure about the region definition? I think it should be `ImplicitRegion[ -2 <= 2 x + 7 y <= 2 && -2 <= 3 x + 6 y <= 2 , {x, y}]`

Comment: Thank you. These don't yield the correct result, though.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks, I just copy the author's code, not aware the picture.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!! Really helpful stuff to learn from. You're a star.

Answer (score 2):

The region defined by the four lines doesn't agree with `Boole[{-8 <= 2 x + 3 y <= 8 && -2 <= 5 x + 2 y <= 2}]` mentioned by OP.

```
regQ = ImplicitRegion[ -8 <= 2 x + 3 y <= 8 && -2 <= 5 x + 2 y <= 2 , {x, y}] (*QP*)
reg = ImplicitRegion[-2 <= 2 x + 7 y <= 2 && -2 <= 3 x + 6 y <= 2, {x,y}] 
Show[{RegionPlot[{regQ, reg}, BoundaryStyle -> { Dashed,Automatic}],ContourPlot[{2 x + 7 y == -2, 2 x + 7 y == 2, 3 x + 6 y == -2,3 x + 6 y == 2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]}]
```

[image]

The correct result follows, in accordance with   @cvgmt 's modified answer, to

```
Integrate[(6 x^2 + 33 x*y + 42 y^2)^4, Element[{x, y}, reg]]
(*4096/225*)
```