# Integration over an implicit region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

A question asks me to calculate the following integral using `NIntegrate`:

[image: Calculate the double integral of (30x^2+37xy+10y^2)^2 over the area D bounded by the four lines 6x+5y=9, 6x+5y=-9, 5x+2y=1 and 5x+2y=-1]

> Calculate the double integral ... where D is the area bounded by the four lines ...

With the following code I only manage to get zero as an answer, which is wrong:

```
f[x_, y_] := (30*x^2 + 37*x*y + 10*y^2)^2

NIntegrate[f[x, y] Boole[6*x + 5*y == 9 && 6*x + 5*y == -9 && 5*x + 2*y == 1 && 
5*x + 2*y == -1], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image: image of code]

What should I do instead?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262725/double-integral-over-special-region/262727#262727

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the region of integration to be defined by inequalities, rather than equalities. Your region can be described as follows:

```
region = ImplicitRegion[Abs[6*x + 5*y] < 9 && Abs[5 x + 2 y] < 1, {x, y}]];
RegionPlot[region, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: representation of the parallelogram bounded by those four lines]

With that definition, you can then write:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, y_] := (30*x^2 + 37*x*y + 10*y^2)^2

NIntegrate[
  f[x, y],
  {x, y} ∈ region
]

(* Out: 24.9231 *)
```

In this case, you can also obtain a symbolic answer, just by replacing `Integrate` for `NIntegrate` above (it returns `324/13`).